# SOLVED -- Equal or Equivalent Inequalities?

Tags: inequality, soft-question

Suppose I have two inequalities:

$2ab \leq a^{2} + b^{2}$

$0 \leq a^{2} + b^{2} - 2ab$

Now, obviously these inequalities are just rearrangements of one another. The question I have is: do I say that these expressions are **equal**, or **equivalent**?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific term for this, but I've usually heard people say one is a rearrangement of the other. If you say equal of equivalent, though, your meaning will be understood.

Comment: Equivalent is fine. Equal  definitely not.

Comment: Thank you for the definitive answer!

Comment: Two *quantities* may be "equal", whereas two *statements* may be "equivalent". Your inequalities are each statements rather than quantities, even though each inequality contains the two quantities being compared via the $\le$ sign.